# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize OauthRawGcsServiceFactory on production environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using appengine-sdk 1.9.3.

In devserver, works in Eclipse and Ant normally.

When I deploy (update) to appengine (production environment), I get this error:

```
event.getResults(): [<pre>Error for /p7/formPanelServlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
    com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.oauth.OauthRawGcsServiceFactory 
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:42) 
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:34)
at com.bitvisio.p7.server.FormPanelServlet.&lt;init&gt;(FormPanelServlet.java:27)
```

At FormPanelServlet.java:27, the code is:

```
private final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory
        .createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
        .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
        .retryMaxAttempts(10)  
        .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
        .build());
```

I put the lib appengine-gcs-client-0.3.9.jar in war/WEB-INF/lib. I think there is a problem with this lib.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Adding which dependency fixed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use tools like Maven or Ivy to resolve dependencies for you. Copying JARs to `war/WEB-INF/lib/` directory and editing `.classpath` file manually will be painful and may not help you always. If you use Eclipse & Google App Engine plugin, use **Add Google APIs...** as mentioned here - [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse). In my case, adding **Cloud Storage API** via Google Plugin for Eclipse helped resolve this `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I use Ivy to resolve dependencies and always get the latest.integration (with Maven use RELEASE) for revisions.

However I usually ignore transitive libraries. It looks like Google is expanding the API family - at least splitting out discrete functionality.

There are now quite a few transitive dependencies and it seems they released a new version of the GCS client around the same time as 1.9.3.

Getting all dependencies and packaging them in my deployment fixed my issue. I did not have the issue in development which made it more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this  issue because you are not  adding the  some of the  jar  like

- google-api-services-storage-v1-rev78-1.22.0.jar [download link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1)
- joda-time-2.94.jar   [download link](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases)
- guava-19.0.jar   [link to download](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release19)

  you can use the  different version of jar according to your appengine-gcs-client jar file.

  Note  : Add all these jar and build path with the project and  problem will get solve. 
  [image]